# How many roots does $f=x^4+x^2+2$ have in $\mathbb Q[x]/(f)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Given an irreducible $f\in \mathbb Q[x]$, how to determine the number of roots of $f=0$ in $\mathbb Q[x]/(f)$?

For some simple examples, I know how to do. If $f(x)=x^2+x-1$, the we use $x\in\mathbb Q[x]/(f)$ to represent $(-1+\sqrt 5)/2$, and $-x-1$ will be another root.

If $f=x^3-2$, $x\in\mathbb Q[x]/(f)$ will represent $2^{1/3}$, and it is the only root of $f=0$ in $\mathbb Q[x]/(f)$, since the other roots are complex.

But for more complicated $f$, e.g. $f=x^4+x^2+2$, I have no idea how to find the number of roots in the extended field. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it helps that $x^4+x^2+2$ is quadratic in $x^2$,and has $4$ complex roots.

Comment: in general this is hard to know, this is part of the knowledge of the Galois group of the polynomial.

Comment: The reasoning in your second example is not right because the field is an abstract field, not a subfield of $\mathbb C$, let alone of $\mathbb R$. You need to argue that if it contained two roots then it'd contain a cubic root of $1$, which it cannot because the degree is odd.

Comment: @ lhf: Can my reasoning for the second example goes like this: Suppose $f=x^3-2$ has another root $ax^2+bx+c$ in $\mathbf Q[x]/(f)$. Then $2^{2/3}a+2^{1/3}b+c$ will be a root of $f$, which is absurd since we know that the others roots should be complex.

Comment: @lhf $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^3-2)$ can be embedded in $\mathbb R$ by the map $x \mapsto 2^{1/3}$, which is injective because all field homomorphisms are injective, at which point the reasoning is entirely valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more concrete way of thinking about it is, if we take one of the roots such as $r = \sqrt{-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}}$, which of the other roots can we express in terms of $r$?

In this case, we have $-r = -\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}}$, another root of $f$. The other two roots are $\pm \sqrt{-1 - r^2}$, so we want to know if there is any element of $\mathbb Q[x]/(f)$ which squares to $-1-x^2$.

The brute force approach is to take an arbitrary element $p = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3$, square it, and check if it's possible to get $p^2 = -1-x^2$. This  is a painful but not really difficult computation; you'll quickly see that either $a_0 = a_2 = 0$ or $a_1 = a_3 = 0$, and then get a quadratic equation to solve with no rational roots.

(So we conclude that $\mathbb Q[x]/(f)$ has only two elements $t$ such that $t^4+t^2+2=0$: $t= \pm x$.)

It might also help to observe that if $p^2 = -1-x^2$, then $(px)^2 = -x^2-x^4 = 2$. I'm pretty sure that this is a contradiction, but I don't actually know what I'm talking about when it comes to field extensions - I just felt really bad when I came across this question and saw everybody interpreting it as "how do I find the roots of $x^4+x^2+2=0$?"

Answer (score 3):

In the case of $ \mathbf Q(2^{1/3}) $, one examines the situation *locally*, by embedding this field into a completion of $ \mathbf Q $ (in this case, $ \mathbf R $) and using what we know about $ \mathbf R $ to deduce that there can only be one root of $ X^3 - 2 $ in this number field. We may do something similar for the field $ \mathbf Q(\alpha) $, where $ \alpha $ is a root of $ X^4 + X^2 + 2 $. Indeed, we have the factorization

$$ X^4 + X^2 + 2 = (X+2)(X+9)(X^2 + 5) \pmod{11} $$

which implies, by Hensel's lemma, that $ X^4 + X^2 + 2 $ has exactly $ 2 $ roots in the field $ \mathbf Q_{11} $ of $ 11 $-adic numbers. Now, we have an embedding $ \mathbf Q(\alpha) \to \mathbf Q_{11} $ by sending $ \alpha $ to either of these roots and extending; therefore, since $ \mathbf Q(\alpha) $ is then realized as a subfield of $ \mathbf Q_{11} $, it can also contain at most two roots of $ X^4 + X^2 + 2 $. We know that it contains at least two, since $ \alpha $ and $ -\alpha $ are distinct roots; therefore it contains exactly two such roots.

Comment: Is it just trial and error that you picked $\mathbb Q_{11}$ to try to factor $x^4+x^2+2$ in? (And will there always be some prime $p$ that works?)

Comment: @MishaLavrov $ 11 $ is trial and error, but by using Chebotarev, one can show that this kind of argument will always work for some prime. (In every nontrivial extension of number fields, there are infinitely many primes which are unramified and do not split completely.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=x^2$.

Then, $f = u^2+u+2$ whose roots are $\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-8}}{2}=-\dfrac12\pm\dfrac{\sqrt7}2i$.

Now, you can find all the $4$ roots, but I will not demonstrate it here for obvious reasons.